# I want to add fading color 'blobs' - PNG is too big, any alternative?

Tags: jquery, flash

I want to do a nice effect that would do something like this:
[image]

So far, I made a separate layer in photoshop for each colour, and I want these to slowly fade in and out. The problem is, however that each blob is about 140KB if I use PNG. Is there a better alternative like doing this in vector and blurring it in jquery? Thanks :))

Comment: 140 kB isn't very much. Is this for a small embedded system, or do you have hundreds of blobs?

Comment: ..Each.
There are about 7 blobs.

Comment: I'm not flash guru, but blurring anything may be very consuming and then slow. But maybe there is glow effect or something similar you can use instead? Or if possible use JPG with white background and change overlay method? Just guessing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few minutes of work below, but I still don't find it as a best solution... I've overcome blur problem with simple gradient - faster... Fading should be JavaScripted.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="width:100%;height:100%">
  <defs>
    <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" />
    </filter>
    <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0); stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:0" />
    </radialGradient>
    <radialGradient id="grad2" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0); stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:0" />
    </radialGradient>
    <radialGradient id="grad3" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,255,255); stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,255,255);stop-opacity:0" />
    </radialGradient>
    <radialGradient id="grad4" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,255); stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,255);stop-opacity:0" />
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>  
  <rect width="100%" height="100%"  style="fill:gray;stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />

  <circle cx="300" cy="200" r="300"  fill="url(#grad1)" >
    <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
  <circle cx="700" cy="600" r="200"  fill="url(#grad2)" >
    <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="0" to="1" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
  <circle cx="100" cy="400" r="150"  fill="url(#grad3)" >
    <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
  <circle cx="400" cy="700" r="500"  fill="url(#grad4)" >
    <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="7s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>

</svg>
```

Comment: FYI. I showed both radial gradients and fading in my answer. So basically are you saying my answer is inferior because I show more options? I'll let the OP choose instead. Still good job integrating then. I think (no time to actually try that now).

Comment: like I said I still don't think svg is best solution, but I've tried it and this is the result. just to summarize our thoughts. I'd put it into comment if it fit... ;)

Comment: Hey guys, no fighting, both of you are the best! I actually thought I would never get an answer for such a complicated task but both of you really outdone yourself which is what really counts here :)))! I am so thankful both to sehe and szamil and I will look at both answers first thing in the morning because it's 2am already :)) Good night guys and thanks :))

Answer (score 1):

Jep.

Have a look at svg. No images whatsoever, the browser renders it

SVG supports animations (declarative) and full javascript scriptability (using the same DOM access as for html).

*Note that the mentioned browser support appears outdated. Many advanced SVG demos work flawless in my Opera browser*

### [Blurring](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_fegaussianblur.asp)

```
<html>
<body>

<p><b>Note: </b>Internet Explorer and Safari do not support SVG filters yet!</p>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="15" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <rect width="90" height="90" stroke="green" stroke-width="3" fill="yellow" filter="url(#f1)" />
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

### [Gradients](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_grad_radial.asp)

```
<html>
<body>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,255);stop-opacity:0" />
      <stop offset="1000%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);stop-opacity:1" />
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
  <ellipse cx="200" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55" fill="url(#grad1)" />
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

### [Fading (animation)](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_animate)

```
<html>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example only works in Firefox and Google Chrome.</p>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <rect x="20" y="20" width="250" height="250" style="fill:blue">
    <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </rect>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is quite heavy to render by the browser, real-time blurring of this 'blob' size... And IE <= 8  doesn't support SVG as far as I know.

Comment: @szamil: Look at these demos and see whether how busy the CPU is: [football](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Soccer_ball_animated.svg), [random walk](http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/randomwalk.svg), [knot](http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/notknot2.svg), [filter turbulence](http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/newstuff/filterTurbulence10.svg), [water](http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/texture/water.svg), [mouse bubbles](http://www.bogotobogo.com/svg_source/bubble.svg), [air balloon](http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/balloon.svg)

Comment: The first ones are very simple, no special effects. But filter turbulence, water (which doesn't work on my FireFox and Chrome, only Opera opens it) or air balloon burst my CPU core (T9300). I have experimented a little with svg lately and large image blurring (not presented in examples you submitted). It is heavy. Consider also that the question was about background, so it cannot takes one core to render!

Comment: @szamil: we both don't know exactly what the OP is going to use it on. However, assuming he wants to just devise the same static overlays (like he _had_ in png, remember) and just fade them in and out slowly, there isn't going to be a problem. At all.